# can't see the cmd error when program shutdown

Tags: cmd

I'm running the VLC player from desktop shortcut, and it immediately shuts down. I can't figure out what is the error written there.

Is there a way of forcing windows into showing the error diplayed in cmd after the program shutdown, either from windows or by setting preferences of the cmd?

Comment: (removed the *dos* tag as I am not aware of a VLC player for DOS ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it directly from cmd.exe instead, and you may see error messages displayed. If not, you might check the "Event Viewer" application to see if anything goes to the system logs.